# How to insert data into SQL Server through gridview without using codebehind file?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

Can anyone tell me how to insert data into a SQL Server database by just using the markup and without using any code in code-behind file.

I can use the gridview's native feature to add and delete but my insert command is not working.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CurrencyCode" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowFooter="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Link1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Add"></asp:LinkButton>
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CurrencyCode" SortExpression="CurrencyCode">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CurrencyCode") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CurrencyCode")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CurrencyCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ModifiedDate" SortExpression="ModifiedDate">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" SelectedDate='<%# Bind("ModifiedDate") %>'></asp:Calendar>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ModifiedDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HomeDBConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Currency] WHERE [CurrencyCode] = @CurrencyCode" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Currency] ([CurrencyCode], [Name], [ModifiedDate]) VALUES (@CurrencyCode, @Name, @ModifiedDate)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Currency]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Currency] SET [Name] = @Name, [ModifiedDate] = @ModifiedDate WHERE [CurrencyCode] = @CurrencyCode">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CurrencyCode" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CurrencyCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedDate" Type="DateTime" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CurrencyCode" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

Comment: Describe "not working". That's far too ambiguous. Does it post back but not insert data? Does it give an error message? Be specific.

Comment: post back happens....but nothing is inserted.
is the code above correct ??

Comment: `aspGridView` doesn't support `InsertTemplate` natively so you have to use some additional controls to insert data to DB and then show them in GridView. A good approach is to use `asp:ListView` which is much more flexible and support all CRUD operations w/out code behind. `asp:listview` was introduced in asp.net 3.5.

Comment: There is an insert command in the sqldatasource tag....I just tried to use that but it's not working. Please let me know if we can use it otherwise list view is a good option.

Comment: do you search on web ? like that one for example: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Insert-Update-Edit-Delete-record-in-GridView-using-SqlDataSource-in-ASPNet.aspx